# How To Display Placeholder Image In Category

Tags: magento-1.9

How to give Condition For Category Image ?
If Category Image Has Not Exist Then Display Placeholder Image/Thumbnail.

How to Write If Else Condition For That?

Code

```
 <?php
    $category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
    $categories = $category->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail'))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
            ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
    ?>
    <ul class="subcategories">
        <?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $category->getUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'catalog' . DS . 'category' . DS . $category->getThumbnail() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>" />
                <span><?php echo $category->getName() ?></span></a>
            </li>   
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

I M uses for :

```
<?php if($category->getThumbnail()): ?>
    <img id="slide-img-1" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($category, 'thumbnail')->resize(135, 135); ?>" /></a>            
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php if($category->getThumbnail()): ?>
    <img id="slide-img-1" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($category, 'thumbnail')->resize(135, 135); ?>" /></a>     
   <?php else: ?>
          <img id="slide-img-1" src="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getBaseMediaUrl(). '/placeholder/' . placeholderUri ?>" /></a>  
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can then get the Magento placeholder URL by replacing placeholderUri above with one of the following, depending on preference:

**Base Image:** `Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/placeholder/image_placeholder')`

**Small Image:** `Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/placeholder/small_image_placeholder')`

**Thumbnail:** `Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/placeholder/thumbnail_placeholder');`

Comment: Getting Error : 
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\inetgp\app\design\frontend\inet\default\template\catalog\category\sub.phtml on line 27

Comment: @RushikeshSolanki I have update the answer please check

Comment: @RushikeshSolanki is your problem solved using above answer?